# What does this unity3d c# code mean?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
Vector3 newDotPosition =
    mouseRay.origin - mouseRay.direction / mouseRay.direction.y * mouseRay.origin.y;
```

I see that newDotPosition is the gameobject's position at the Terrain. But what does the following code do?

```
mouseRay.direction / mouseRay.direction.y * mouseRay.origin.y
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's some basic geometry.

`mouseRay.origin` is camera's world position. So `mouseRay.origin.y` is camera's height.

Result of `mouseRay.direction / mouseRay.direction.y * mouseRay.origin.y` is the red vector in image below. It just scales `mouseRay.direction` all the way through the ground.

Then it does `mouseRay.origin - result` to get the hit point on ground in world coordinates.

[image]

And here is the code to see the result if anyone interested.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float originGizmoRadius = 1f;
    public float newDotPositionGizmoSize = 0.5f;
    public float directionLength = 2f;

    Vector3 origin;
    Vector3 direction;
    Vector3 newDotPosition;

    void Update()
    {
        Ray mouseRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        origin = mouseRay.origin;
        direction = mouseRay.direction;

        newDotPosition = origin - direction / direction.y * origin.y;
    }

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(origin, originGizmoRadius);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(origin, origin + (direction.normalized * directionLength));

        Gizmos.color = Color.green;
        Gizmos.DrawCube(newDotPosition, newDotPositionGizmoSize * Vector3.one);
    }
}
```